# "/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper" error when opening terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, python, paths, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (clean installation, I did not upgrade from a previous one) and when I open a new terminal (simply by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), it always starts with the output shown below (also shown in the following screenshot):

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
daniel@daniel-Inspiron-5482:~$
```

[image: unclear terminal]

Of course I have already tried to execute reset and reboot.

In the past I did have a problem with these paths, so the commands I had executed to fix the path were:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Here is my `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
# Virtual Environment Wrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# Virtual Environment Wrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/daniel/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/daniel/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/daniel/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/daniel/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I have also installed the packages `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` and updated using `sudo apt`, but the problem still accrues.

What is the problem with my terminal actually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this entry in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
# Virtual Environment Wrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# Virtual Environment Wrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

1. It's a duplicate entry. You only need one, so just remove the other.
2. Make sure that the path to `virtualenvwrapper.sh` is the correct one by running the following command and replacing `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` with the command's output:

   ```
   which virtualenvwrapper.sh
   ```

   If the path is already the correct one, then great! Just skip this step.
3. You need to add these commands (that you also mention in your question) right before `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```bsh
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
   export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
   ```

   Again, you should make sure that the paths are the correct ones.
4. After doing the above, restart your terminal or run:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

Your terminal should start properly now, without the error text, and `virtualenvwrapper` should work as expected!